# For loop in R: How to store all outputs in loop?

Tags: r

I want to save all outputs in loop and then plot output versus `j`. I tried a lot of things but I didn't store all outputs. At end of the program I just have one variable. Here is my code:

```
Tsim <- 0.815
toplam <- 0
toplam_ortalama_enerji <- 0
toplam_ortalama_enerji_kare <- 0
mydata <- read.table("/local/syaman/1RLQ_cm3.680-6.400_GO_KEFC1.40_e1.00_T0.815_ii4_trj.dat")

x <- mydata[-1:-5000,]
enerji <- x[,3]
l <- length(enerji)
step <- seq(0.1, 2.5, by=0.001)

for(j in step){
    sicaklik = j + sicaklik
    for(i in 1:l){
        Si = exp((enerji[i]/Tsim)-(enerji[i]/sicaklik))
        toplam = toplam + Si
        ortalama_enerji <- enerji[i]*Si
        toplam_ortalama_enerji <- toplam_ortalama_enerji + ortalama_enerji
        ortalama_enerji_kare <- enerji[i]*enerji[i]*Si
        toplam_ortalama_enerji_kare <- toplam_ortalama_enerji_kare + ortalama_enerji_kare
    }
    isi_kapasitesi = ((toplam_ortalama_enerji_kare/toplam)-((toplam_ortalama_enerji/toplam)*(toplam_ortalama_enerji/toplam)))/(sicaklik*sicaklik)
    print(isi_kapasitesi)
}
```

I want to save all `isi_kapasitesi`.

Comment: Use `lapply` not `for`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess something basic like this is all you need?

```
storage = c()
for(j in step){
   ...
   storage = c(storage, isi_kapasitesi)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a for loop like this you need to first create isi_kapasitesi as a list outside of the loop and then store each individual element as follows:

```
isi_kapasitesi <- list()
for(j in 1:length(step)){
sicaklik = step[j] + sicaklik
for(i in 1:l){
    Si = exp((enerji[i]/Tsim)-(enerji[i]/sicaklik))
    toplam = toplam + Si
    ortalama_enerji <- enerji[i]*Si
    toplam_ortalama_enerji <- toplam_ortalama_enerji + ortalama_enerji
    ortalama_enerji_kare <- enerji[i]*enerji[i]*Si
    toplam_ortalama_enerji_kare <- toplam_ortalama_enerji_kare + ortalama_enerji_kare
}
isi_kapasitesi[j] = ((toplam_ortalama_enerji_kare/toplam)-((toplam_ortalama_enerji/toplam)*(toplam_ortalama_enerji/toplam)))/(sicaklik*sicaklik)
print(isi_kapasitesi[j])
```

The way you had it written before you were only storing the last value in the loop.

Comment: I want to ask something why you use isi_kapasitesi[ i ] instead of isi_kapasitesi[ j ]

Comment: Sorry, what I have previously written actually won't work. I'll update my solution now.

Comment: The first loop had j as an element of the step variable e.g. 0.1 .. I've changed it so that j is an index that will run for the number of steps.. This also means setting    sicaklik = step[j] + sicaklik